# phpMyAdmin Replace Query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I recently encountered an error when running a query in phpMyAdmin to replace the values copied over from my main site's database, with the values of my staging site's database.

I have run this query in the past and it was able to replace the values for the staging site's database and found it strange that it doesn't work now? Would you know why this is occurring?

**You can see the query that I ran in phpMyAdmin below:**

```
UPDATE wp2_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, ‘example.org’, ‘dev.example.org’);
UPDATE wp2_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, ‘example.org’, ‘dev.example.org’);
UPDATE wp2_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, ‘example.org’, ‘dev.example.org’);
UPDATE wp2_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, ‘example.org’, ‘dev.example.org’);
```

**You can see the error that followed from running the query in phpMyAdmin below:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://example.orgâ€™, â€˜[http://dev.example.orgâ](http://dev.example.org%C3%A2)€™)' at line 1

Thanks,

Josh Gomes

Comment: Are you writing code in Word? Those quotes `‘` should be of the proper kind: `'`. Use a proper editor, for example like Notepad++

Comment: single quotes should be like this '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using apostrophes `‘` and `’` instead of single (or double) quotes.

Both of the following queries should work :

```
UPDATE wp2_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'example.org', 'dev.example.org');
```

And

```
UPDATE wp2_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, "example.org", "dev.example.org");
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback it worked fine! I copied the script over to word and I will make sure I use Komodo in future.